# Pass value to ExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

I have a `WebAPI` project and am moving my `exception` catching from `try/catch` to `exception` `filters`. Previously when I used `try/catch` blocks I was able to access the `SQL` command object to get the `SQL` command text to log to the database. Now that I moving to exception filters I am no longer able to access the `SQL` command object. What I am after is a way to pass the `SQL` command which was last executed to the exception filter so that I can still log it.

Previous code (try/catch blocks)

```
public HttpResponseMessage API([FromBody] int roomID)
{
    HttpResponseMessage msg = null;
    SqlCommand comm = Common.Shared.ConnectDB();

    try
    {
        List<Models.room> room = room(comm, roomID);
        msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, room);
    }
    catch (CustomException ex)
    {
        msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        comm.Parameters.Clear();
        var sourceFunction = "rooms";
        var returnException = Common.Logging.CreateLog(ex, comm, sourceFunction);
        msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, returnException);
    }
    finally
    {
        comm.Connection.Close();
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Exception Filter code

```
public class InternalServerErrorFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        Log.Error(context.Exception, "Exception Information");

        context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Controller Exception Filter

```
[InternalServerErrorFilter]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage API([FromBody] int roomID)
{
    HttpResponseMessage msg = null;
    SqlCommand comm = Common.Shared.ConnectDB();

    try
    {
        List<Models.room> room = room(comm, roomID);
        msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, room);
    }
    finally
    {
        comm.Connection.Close();
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways you could handle that scenario:

Check and cast `Exception` type into more specific exception, like `SqlException`(Check [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx)). Inside `SqlException` you'll be able to find reason for that exception.

```
public class InternalServerErrorFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is SqlException)
        {
           var sqlException = (SqlException)context.Exception;
           //Do your logging...
        }
        context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Or you could create your custom sql exception, to which you'll pass your `SqlCommand` for further logging. However, you'll need to check type (like above) in order to get strongly-typed access.

```
public class CustomSqlException : Exception
{
    public SqlCommand ExecutedCommand { get; }

    public CustomException(SqlCommand executedCommand) 
        : base("Custom Message")
    {
        ExecutedCommand = executedCommand;
    }
}

public class InternalServerErrorFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is CustomSqlException)
        {
            var sqlException = (CustomSqlException)context.Exception;
            var command = sqlException.ExecutedCommand;
            //Do your logging...
        }
        context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
[InternalServerErrorFilter]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage API([FromBody] int roomID)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage msg = null;
        SqlCommand comm = Common.Shared.ConnectDB();

        try
        {
            List<Models.room> room = room(comm, roomID);
            msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, room);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
           throw new CustomSqlException(comm);
        }
        finally
        {
            comm.Connection.Close();
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

I would suggest you use first approach, because `SqlException` should have all necessary information about error which ocurred while executing SQL command on SQL server. In addition to that, you will not lose your stack trace, due to throwing new exception.

If you decide to go with the second solution, you could circumvent issue of losing stack trace by passing exception as inner exception of your `CustomSqlException`.

Comment: This would work for SQL exceptions. However I was also hoping to grab the SQL command for other exceptions, such as those thrown by data readers etc. These don't throw SQL exceptions and as such I won't get the Command string which was used by the data reader etc

Comment: @Nathan then you could go with second option. However, you'll need to handle exception raised by data readers manually. You don't have to catch `SqlException`, you could catch `Exception`.